# Display error about databinding listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, data-binding, listbox

**allow me to describe the error first.**

**1. display order error**

listbox will display items while begin with the second one, and the first goes to the last but four. the last item also has the same problem.

[first item missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbggC.jpg)

[last 3 or 4 items order mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn5ES.jpg)

**2. row missing error**

when i bind the listbox with a datatable which has more than 400 rows, the first item will miss, and so is the last one.

**then post the code here**

**1. using accdb to store data**

here is the c# code to get data from a access database in a oledb way. i hope i get it right...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataSet DsMain = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter Dpter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string StartPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\AltiumDatabase.accdb";
        Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + StartPath);

        try
        {
            Conn.Open();

            string strcmd = "select ID,TaskType, Status,StatusColor,PN,Type,Owner,Checker,Deadline,StartDate,Tag from TRRecord";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strcmd, Conn);
            Dpter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            Dpter.Fill(DsMain, "TRRecord");

            LbxMain.DataContext = DsMain;//bind to the listbox
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**2. custom listbox building**

i hope i get all binding declears all right ...

```
<ListBox Name="LbxMain" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TRRecord}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="5">
                    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=StatusColor}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=PN}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=TaskType}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

should i use INotifyPorpertyChanged or ObservableCollection? i just bind data after fill the table, so no any changes then, do they really matter?
i really appreciate it if someone help. and thanks to everyone read this post.

errr...my english is not that good. so please tell me if somewhere i havn't describe clearly.

Comment: errr...i seem just find the key to this problem. cause each listboxitem has a complex content, i should give a specific rule to sort which means to use ListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("ID", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)); lol...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the next way of binding.

```
LbxMain.DataContext = DsMain.Tables["TRRecord"];
```

In addition in your XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="LbxMain" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding }" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"> ... </ListBox>
```

Regards.

Comment: thaks for your answer. 
i tried your way to set databinding, but it doesn't work ether. 
in my opinion, this is all about how to sort items added in listbox. the confusing thing here is how "it" decide the order for displaying items on control UI, especially for my data shown above that has ID, status, partnumber and other properties.
i now give the listbox a new SortDescription, and all items now show in the very order i want. so i think the key here is you should give your own sort description, rather than how you build the databinding.
still thanks, and looking forward your other thoughts